What if we include a “zero-point energy” tensor in the EFEs?
The cosmological constant problem roughly states that the predicted value of $\Lambda$ becomes mostly infinite even though we only measure negligible values for it.
In classic General Relativity, the zero-point energy of a system is identically zero, so if there are zero particles then there is zero energy. In the case of QFT the Hamiltonian of a vacuum state tends to diverge. This would, in principle, infinitely curve spacetime producing the net effect of an infinite expansion.
Nonetheless, one could break down the total energy-momentum tensor $\mathcal{T}_{\mu\nu}$ into its classical $T_{\mu\nu}$ version and a quantum mechanical one $\Psi_{\mu\nu}$ that includes the divergence corresponding to the zero-point energy of the quantum system. Now, given that the diverging Hamiltonian is independent of spacetime coordinates then we should have
$$\Psi_{\mu\nu} = \xi g_{\mu\nu},$$
So we can “renormalize” the theory’s Lagrangian by including this diverging term into the action
$$S = \int{\sqrt{-g}\left[\frac{1}{2\kappa}R + \frac{\Lambda}{\kappa} + \mathcal{L}_m - \xi\right]},$$
(here using the mostly minus convention). The EFEs become
$$G_{\mu\nu} = \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} + \kappa \mathcal{T}_{\mu\nu} - \xi\kappa g_{\mu\nu} = \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} + \kappa T_{\mu\nu}.$$
Could this renormalization procedure help with the cosmological constant problem? Is it equal to normal-ordering the right hand side?

"the zero-point energy of a system is identically zero, so if there are zero particles then there is zero energy" - that's the thing, even in $m=0$ flat spacetime, accounting for the cosmological constant gives a small vacuum energy (which does not align with what is predicted with QFT). I don't know enough about the specifics of vacuum QFT to talk about it but that's the note I have to add.

This question is similar to: Can the cosmological constant problem be solved by imposing that the renormalized value matches the observed value?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The "cosmological constant problem" is a non-problem, consider $\Lambda$ as a fundamental constant and the problem vanishes.

@JeanbaptisteRoux There is no $\Lambda$, it’s an artifact of the failed Friedmann cosmology.
